# jQuery image upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, upload

I'm writing announcements module on my website and want to allow users to upload 3-5 photos with announcement. So I'm looking for a ready solution that will allow them to upload photos, make one of the photos main, etc.
Here is the snapshot what I want to acheive:

[image]

But I think its hopeless and there no such plugin so I would have to write my own wrapper around some of jquery upload plugins like valums or uploadify etc.
The only problem is I'm only getting familiar with such things like ajax and jquery plugins.
So I would really appreciate any info and links that would help me to acheive what I desire.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You said "I'm writing...", then "I'm looking for a ready solution"...

Comment: So why isn't valums or uploadify good enough for you?

Comment: Damien, writing module and looking for a solution for uploading images without page refreshing. I think both of them would be good, but I've decided to try the luck for a ready plugin but it have no results. So I'm asking about what plugin is the best by people opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find jQuery plugin for what you want, there are multiple file uploaders but non of them showing thumbnails before upload, there is a Flash file uploader if you interested from [Element-it](http://www.element-it.com/) but its not free.

http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx

Comment: You can use it with php. Description on site says `Standard script which receives files on server. Flash upload with ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, ColdFusion and Perl server scripts examples are included.`